# Laravel + Angular - Get 401 unauthenticated on 1 GET method

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm developing a Laravel + Angular app and i'm getting 401 Unauthorized in only 1 GET request.

Here I explain how I developed my authentication and how it work on Backend and Frontend. I wish you can help me.

I use Laravel Sanctum for manage authentication in my app. Here is how I program the backend.

I get users from my BD table:

**Note:** I have created a separate controller, to separate the authentication functions from the user functions, even so, I have tried to put this function in my AuthController and it has not given me any result.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllUsers()
    {
        return User::all();
    }

}
```

As I want you to only be able to retrieve all the DB users if you are authenticated, in my api.php file I put the path inside the middleware:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function() 
{
    Route::post('logout', [\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::get('getAuthUser', [\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'getAuthUser']);

    //Admin actions
    Route::post('createUser', [\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'createUser']);
    Route::get('getAllUsers', [\App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::class, 'getAllUsers']);
});
```

If I make the request from the Postman everything works correctly, if I am not authenticated it gives me an error and if I have previously authenticated it returns all the DB users just as I expected. By the way, I am using cookies to send the jwt to the Frontend.

The problem is when in my Angular app I request my backend with the GET method to retrieve these users and display them in a table. In addition, the code to retrieve the users is within a condition in which it is looking at whether the user is authenticated or not. The truth is that I do not understand what may be happening.

```
getUsers(): void
  {
    //Check if user is authenticated
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/getAuthUser', { withCredentials: true }). subscribe(
      (res: any) =>
      {
        Emitters.authEmitter.emit(true);
        Emitters.roleEmitter.emit(res.role);
        
        

        //Get all users
        this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getAllUsers', { withCredentials: true }). subscribe(
          res =>
          {
            this.users = res;
          }
        )
      },
      err =>
      {
        Emitters.authEmitter.emit(false);
        Emitters.roleEmitter.emit("none");
        alert("You should be authenticated for this.");
      }
    );
  }
```

The first request that you see above getAuthUser, makes the request to the Backend in the same way as the second request getAllUsers and the first one works perfectly and the second one does not, it is in which I get an err. I call the getUsers() method in the ngInit().

I hope I have explained myself well. Any information you need to know let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the request that gave the error to change the path of the api, instead of putting 127.0.0.1 putting localhost.